# How add css in .ashx.cs code behind in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, ashx

I want to add `css class` in **.ashx** page but **.aspx Ui** page show as `string`.
How to add `css` in .ashx code behinde page.

**I want (Cook) text show in red.**

Issue:

[image]

```html
     try
            {
    for (int i = 0; i < dsSeaech.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var myString = new StringBuilder();
                    myString.Append("<span style=\"color:red\">(Cook)</span>");                 
                    lstRecipeName.Add(dsSeaech.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RecipeName"].ToString());
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(dsSeaech.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserType"]) == AppConstant.chefuser)
                    {
                        lstChefName.Add(dsSeaech.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FullName"].ToString() + "(" + "Chef" + ")");
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(dsSeaech.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserType"]) == AppConstant.cook)
                    {
                        lstChefName.Add(dsSeaech.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FullName"].ToString() + myString);
                    }
                }
                
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(lstRecipeName));
                }
                 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Comment: what client side code you have done to achieve this? it seems it is considering it string because it is encoded as string within the JSON response

Comment: I use ASHX handler for searching   and it not allow UI.

Comment: This is client side code  <input type="text" id="txtsearch" placeholder="Search by recipe name or cook/chef name" class="form-control custom-form-control">

Comment: you reply doesnt explain anything, how you are sending the input value to server and binding it to the dropdown?

Comment: fill text in textBox then     $('#txtsearch').autocomplete({                
                source: 'Search.ashx'
            });  then Search.ashx page and bind context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(lstRecipeName));

Comment: this is text box.  <input type="text" id="txtsearch" placeholder="Search by recipe name or cook/chef name" class="form-control custom-form-control">

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_renderItem` event of the autocomplete.

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append('<a>'+item.label+'</a>')
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

here's fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/192m0uyc/9/